# Issues with Positioning Image on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So, I'm working on a component, on Wordpress for website, where I need to put an "SOLD OUT" image over a list of text and I've done just that.  But the problem is when I look at website on a mobile device. The images are smaller and one of the images is not where it's suppose to be.  That's because I use the "absolute" property.

I know that I have to use media queries to make it responsive, but I don't have access to the external CSS stylesheet to use media queries.  And I can't use media queries in html.

Does anyone have any idea or advice? I would like some help or advice on this.

Here's the website link: https://ncch.org/event/golf-2019/

Comment: Hey, @ericp0514 could you please add your relevant html and css and separate your code into code blocks. Check this guide if you need help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The container surrounding the image, you can give it

```
position:relative;
```

And remove left styling